# Angular 4 Loading Component center vertically and horizontally

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, view, components

I am working on creating a loading component that I can use in multiple places on my website in Angular 4, with Bootstrap 4. I have the content centered horizontally inside of my div however I cannot get the text, and icon to center inside the div. I am using Font-Awesome for icons.

You ever just write so much HTML that your brain stops working and all of a sudden you cannot find a solution to center some text and a spinning icon? Because that is where I am at right now.

Loading Component Html:

```
<div class="text-center" [style.height.px]="height" [style.cursor]="loading? 'not-allowed': ''">
  <div [style.height.px]="height" class="display-inline-block align-middle justify-content-center">
    <h3>{{loadingText}}</h3>
    <i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-5x"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Custom CSS:

```
.display-inline-block
{
    display:inline-block;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Screenshot:
[image]